# SQL results unwanted Spaces in data to csv

Tags: ssms, trim, space

I'm using SQL server (SSMS 18). I have a stored proc which returns data to Visual studio. To remove leading/trailing spaces, I'm using LTRIM(RTRIM([FNAME])) as [FNAME] etc. The data is being writing to a "|" delimited csv file in c#. Problem is in spite of using LTRIM, RTRIM I still see spaces. some of the data I see in c#  in the IEnumerable, it looks like

```
"SOSA\0"
" NEHA\0"
```

Then in the csv file it looks like

```
DABBY |MILLER |
```

I'm not sure what kind of spaces are those and how to get rid of them.

Comment: Here's a guide how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your version of SSMS (18 in this case) is largely irrelevant. SSMS 18 supports SQL Server 2008-2019; that's 6.5 different versions of SQL Server. It's tagging [[tag:sql-server]] and its version that's important.

Comment: I mentioned SSMS 18 since for ex, SQL 16 has introduced TRIM() function, which cares for leading/trailing spaces. But in my case it does not work somehow and I get 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: I think I will try RegularExpressions in c# code and see it that works. will update post